The wampserver icon is orange and it seems that 'The service 'wampmysqld64' is NOT started'
enter image description hereenter image description hereThere is no port conflict and the mysql service is shutdown. I'm wondering whether the image above tells me that wampmysqld64 is running:<
Since there is no port conflict and the mysql service is shutdown(general solutions), I have no idea what to do next.
